# auto refresh div containing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I want to refresh a DIV that has a JavaScript inside it every 5 seconds. I tried this code, but it only refreshes one time. how can I make it execute the JavaScript code every five seconds ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#content').load('count.html');
}, 5000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    today = new Date();
    BigDay = new Date("December 25, 2020");
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
    e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
    hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
    minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft)*60);
    document.write("There are only<BR> <H4>" + daysLeft + " days " + hrsLeft +" hours and " + minsLeft + " minutes left </H4> Until December 25th 2020<P>");
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I replace your `$("#content").load()` by `alert()` it works fine..  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hldLe

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503478/auto-refresh-div-contents-every-5-seconds-code-not-working

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer to another question here: [Auto Refresh DIV contents every 5 seconds code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503478/auto-refresh-div-contents-every-5-seconds-code-not-working)

---

> I think your refresh function is incomplete, for instance there's nothing that makes it loop. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var seconds = 5000; // time in milliseconds
var reload = function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'editStatus.jsp',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#refreshDIV').html(data);
          setTimeout(function() {
             reload();
          }, seconds);
      }
   });
 };
 reload();
});
```

Comment: this is spam answer you can see the duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503478/auto-refresh-div-contents-every-5-seconds-code-not-working

Comment: @Sandeep When you copy content from elsewhere, you **must* attribute the source. Further, you should not simply copy-paste the whole thing, but include your own wording in an answer, with the referenced information just for support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
     $('#content').load('count.html');
     }, 5000);
});
```